# Navigation Interaction Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

anyone knows, why does matplotlib interaction navigation not appear?
[Click to see the picture Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isq88.jpg)
how to show it again ?
this is my code :

```
        df = pd.read_csv('cluster/export/with_reduction+label_dataset.csv')
        finalDf = df.iloc[:, 1:]
        print(type(finalDf))
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=80)
        # height, width, plot
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        ax.set_xlabel('X', fontsize=15)
        ax.set_ylabel('Y', fontsize=15)
        ax.set_title('Testing', fontsize=20)

        targets = ['Iman', 'Wudlu', 'Mandi', 'Haidl', 'Shalat', 'Adzan', 'Shaum']
        colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'crimson', 'chocolate', 'orange', 'violet']
        for target, color in zip(targets, colors):
            indicesToKeep = finalDf['nm_bab'] == target
            ax.scatter(finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'component_1']
                       , finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'component_2']
                       , c=color
                       , s=60
                       , label=target
                       , marker='o')
        # ax.plot()
        ax.legend()
        ax.grid()
        plt.show()
```

Comment: First thing to check is: Does it also not appear when doing `plt.plot([1,2,4]); plt.show()`? If so, you may simplify your code in the question, if not, add your code line by line to the minimal example and see at which point it starts disappearing. Report about those findings in your question.

Comment: thank you for your reply, the problem above has been solved, it just because of my matplotlib is doesn't update. i am using matplotlib 2.2.3 now